# Switchyard. How to route messages in Reciever Service?

Tags: java, switchyard

Switchyard is new thing for me, and i'm quite lost in where to look.
What i have i two services connected by ESB.
From sender i send simple class with data. Based on type of class i want
receiver side decide what to do. 
So type of class will be action, and data in that class will be used as values for that action.

For example if i want to create new Customer i send to bus something like this:

```
class CreateCustomerMessage{
  public String fName;
  public String lName;
  public Int age;
}
```

receiver gets message, sees that he has to create customer and routes this message to

```
class CustomerOperationsBean{
  public Long createCustomer(CreateCustomerMessage message){...}
}
```

And creates this customer.
Can please someone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here what i've found.
If you have a CamelService ( i use java routing config ) you can match against incoming message class using construction similar to this :

```
public void configure() {
 from("switchyard://QueueConsumerService")
        .choice()
                .when(body(InventoryRequest.class))
                    .log("Received Inventory message : ${body}")
                    .to("some_endpoint")
                .when(body(AuditRequest.class))
                    .log("Audit request : ${body}");
                    .to("some_other_endpoint")
}
```

and that's it. 
**some_endpoint** and **some_other_endpoint** here can be any endpoint, java class or another Camel router. 
gl hf.